# Selenium Finding elements by class name and value in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Is there a way to use `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ...)` to find an element specifying NOT ONLY its class, but also the class value?

I know this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='class_value'")
```

But how can I add the value filter?

Comment: Please edit your question and update with relevant HTML and your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can locate elements by any attributes including any possible combinations of them.
So, to locate element based on it `class` name attribute value and `value` attribute value it can be something like this

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@class='class_value' and @value='value_value']")
```

In case there are other `class` attribute values or / and `value` attribute values we can use `contains` as following

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'class_value') and contains(@value,'value_value')]")
```

Or (the same as above, just different syntax)

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class,'class_value')][contains(@value,'value_value')]")
```